multipart/form-data request to Google Drive API in React Native
 I’m trying to send a multipart/form-data request to the Google Drive API from my React Native app.  When I use Postman, the request works perfectly, but when I try to implement the same request in React Native using fetch or axios, I keep getting a "Malformed multipart body" error.
I’m constructing the request using FormData, adding metadata (metadata) and the file (file). This setup works fine in Postman, so I suspect there’s something different in how React Native handles FormData or the Content-Type header for multipart requests.
Has anyone experienced this issue in React Native? Is there a specific way to configure FormData to behave the same way as it does in Postman?  Or, if you have any recommendations for alternative approaches to send multipart/form-data requests from React Native, I’d really appreciate the guidance.
Thanks in advance for any help!

export const uploadToGoogleDrive = async (data) => {
  try {
    const accessToken = await signInWithGoogle();
    const fileName = data.title;
    const fileDescription = data.description;
    const file = data.file;
    const fileMimeType = file.assets[0].mimeType;

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("metadata", JSON.stringify({
      name: fileName,
      mimeType: fileMimeType,
      description: fileDescription,
      parents: [GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID]
    }), { type: 'application/json' });

    formData.append('file', {
      uri: file.assets[0].uri,
      type: fileMimeType,
      name: fileName,
    });

    const response = await fetch(`${GOOGLE_DRIVE_ENDPOINT}/files?uploadType=multipart`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
      body: formData,
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorText = await response.json();
      console.log("Detailed Error:", errorText);
      throw new Error(`Error uploading file: ${response.statusText}, details: ${errorText}`);
    }

    return response;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Upload error:", error);
    if (error.response) {
      console.error("Response data:", error.response.data);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.error("Request details:", error.request);
    } else {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
    }
  }
};


Unfortunately, I couldn't understand that in your showing script, which you are using FormData and fetch of the native node.js or of other packages. From { type: 'application/json' }, I guessed that you might be using FormData and fetch of the native node.js. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?
In this modification, it supposes that file.assets[0].uri is the file path. Please be careful about this. If it's the direct link of the URL, please modify the script.
Also, this modification supposes that GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID and GOOGLE_DRIVE_ENDPOINT have already been declaread, and your access token accessToken is valid for uploading the file. Also, please be careful about this.
Modified script:
In this modification, const fs = require("fs"); is required to be loaded.
export const uploadToGoogleDrive = async (data) => {
  try {
    const accessToken = await signInWithGoogle();
    const fileName = data.title;
    const fileDescription = data.description;
    const file = data.file;
    const fileMimeType = file.assets[0].mimeType;

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append(
      "metadata",
      new Blob(
        [
          JSON.stringify({
            name: fileName,
            mimeType: fileMimeType,
            description: fileDescription,
            parents: [GOOGLE_DRIVE_FOLDER_ID],
          }),
        ],
        { type: "application/json" }
      )
    );

    formData.append("file", await fs.openAsBlob(file.assets[0].uri, { type: fileMimeType }));

    const response = await fetch(`${GOOGLE_DRIVE_ENDPOINT}/files?uploadType=multipart`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
        body: formData,
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorText = await response.json();
      console.log("Detailed Error:", errorText);
      throw new Error(`Error uploading file: ${response.statusText}, details: ${errorText}`);
    }
    return response;

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Upload error:", error);
    if (error.response) {
      console.error("Response data:", error.response.data);
    } else if (error.request) {
      console.error("Request details:", error.request);
    } else {
      console.error("Error:", error.message);
    }
  }
};


When I tested this modified script using my valid access token and a sample file, I confirmed that the file could be correctly uploaded.


Thank you for the response! I'm using React Native, not Node.js, so I don't have access to the fs module. I’ve tried both react-native-fs and Expo’s File System, and my file path looks like this: file:///data/user/0/com.myApp/cache/imageName.jpg, but the upload still isn’t working. Do you have any advice for handling file uploads to Google Drive in React Native without Node-specific modules?

@Alexa Thank you for replying. About I don't have access to the fs module., although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, how about modifying my script from formData.append("file", await fs.openAsBlob(file.assets[0].uri, { type: fileMimeType })); to formData.append('file', { uri: file.assets[0].uri, type: fileMimeType, name: fileName });?

@Alexa In order to upload the data to Google Drive, the file content is required to be used. If this modification is not useful, in your situation, can I ask you about the method for retrieving the content from a file from a file path of file.assets[0].uri?
